# how to make Relative layout onclick work?

Tags: android, xml, onclicklistener

I have a Relative layout as:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/iPay_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="· Use iPay"
            android:textColor="#686A86"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/i_pay"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want my relative layout to perform onCLickListener but does not work.
I am able to do the setonclicklistener but it works only with the textview part and not for the image.

```
    btniPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //for ipay

        }
    });
```

This works for the text part only but not for the image. Any idea what I might be missing.

Comment: Use an ImageView instead of a Button (or simply a View, each View object has the background attribute)... Button is clickable by default, then clicks are not passed to the surrounding RelativeLayout.

Comment: In a layout almost indentical to this example, I am unable to make the RelativeLayout itself clickable, but the Imagebutton works fine. Are there more possible traps in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can add **android:clickable="false"** in your button xml attribute.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/iPay_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="· Use iPay"
        android:textColor="#686A86"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/i_pay"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This had no effect in my case, see comment above

Comment: or you can set android:duplicateParentState=“true” to the children of relativeLayout

Answer (score 1):

may be you can find some good example thats use with imageview and buttons but the easy way i did it by using adding TextView instead of images and buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/englishheading1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/urduheading1"
                android:text="English text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/urduheading1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="urdu text1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is java code to perform `onClick`.

```
RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do something
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

see my code easily run change your code:

.xml file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/iPay_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="· Use iPay"
                android:textColor="#686A86"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

.java file

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        TextView tv;
        Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark `android:clickable="true"` in your `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_id"
    android:clickable="true">
```

Using **ButterKnife** lib make bind here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xml_name);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

@OnClick(R.id.activity_id)
void onActivityClick() {
      // do smth ...
}
```